# gzip maximum compression using ant

Tags: java, ant, gzip

The [GZip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pack.html) task in ant works no problem, but is there a way to get it to use maximum compression - the equivalent of `gzip -9`?

I don't want to just use the native `exec` task because then I'll lose cross platform compatibility.

The reason I ask is because I need to compress the changelog with gzip to include in a debian package (also generated via ant) and unless it uses maximum comrpession lintian spouts out a warning (which I'd obviously like to avoid.)

Comment: You could just use the `exec` task and invoke gzip yourself

Comment: @fge Problem with that is it'll fail in environments where gzip isn't installed, I'd like to keep it cross platform where possible.

Comment: Hmm, "debian", "cross platform"... Are there any debian versions without gzip installed? ;)

Comment: Sounds like a good enhancement for this task.

Comment: @fge Just because I'm building a Debian package doesn't mean I have to build it on Debian. I'm building it quite happily on Windows at the moment (as well as any other OS via the ant-deb task) and I'd like to keep it that way!

Comment: @PeterLawrey provided ant doesn't use Java's Gzip*Stream classes however, since these don't give a choice as to the compression ratio. It'd mean recoding it...

Comment: @fge, It only supports DEFAULT_COMPRESSION (in Java 7) rather than BEST_COMPRESSION. Patching the class and using it in the JDK could be a workaround.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52414 Just filed that, can see what happens with it!

Comment: just write your own task, it's trivial. would take less time than asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you create a small program with this 
http://commons.apache.org/compress/

try this .. http://bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/178 for setting compression level feature to GZipOut Stream

Comment: I had a quick look at the javadocs and couldn't see any option there for specifying the compression ratio? Perhaps I'm missing it.

Comment: you can set comepression ratio like this zipOutputStream.setLevel(9); see  my edit in answer. hope that helps

Comment: I see it for the ZipOutputStream - I just can't see an equivalent one on the GZip streams which is what I'd need.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the best option at least for now!